# Gulp-rev replacing files with generated hash

Tags: hash, gulp, gulp-rename, gulp-rev

I started using Gulp and I want to create a task that renames the files(js,css) with hash and then inject them back into the html.

I actually have two functions that do what I want, but I can't figure out how to delete the old file and keep just the new js and css hashed files.

Some could give me a hint? This is my code right now:

obs: 'config' variable has the folder locations

```
gulp.task('prod:rev',['prod:revision'],function() { 
  var manifest = gulp.src(config.prod.manifest);
  return gulp
    .src(config.prod.header)
    .pipe(plugin.revReplace({manifest: manifest}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
});

gulp.task('prod:revision',function(){
  var revJs = gulp
   .src(config.scripts.build+'*.js')
   .pipe(plugin.rev())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scripts.build))
   .pipe(plugin.rev.manifest({merge: true}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(config.prod.path));

  var revCss = gulp
   .src(config.styles.build+'*.css')
   .pipe(plugin.rev())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(config.styles.build))
   .pipe(plugin.rev.manifest({merge: true}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(config.prod.path));

  return merge(revJs,revCss);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have currently an open [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678401/cant-get-gulp-rev-replace-working-with-gulp-useref) on a similar issue - I get the files revved properly, but fail to inject them in the html with gulp-useref (you can check the supposed-to-work method in my question regarding useref). I suspect some foul play with the directories I use, but for now I've chosen to use a different cache-busting scheme:

```
var cb = Math.random();

....
.pipe($.replace('dist/css/lib.css', 'dist/css/lib.css?cb=' + cb))
....
```

It may not be the answer you want, but it may be an answer you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `gulp-rev` [readme.md](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev#works-with-gulp-rev) it sounds like you might want to also use `gulp-rev-delete-original` to delete the unhashed originals.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this after calling .pipe(rev())

const revDelete = require('gulp-rev-delete-original');

...
**.pipe(revDelete())**
...

That will delete the 'unhashed' files.